# npm ERR! cb.apply is not a function (Elementary OS)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

I am very new to react native and nodejs . Today I installed nodejs on my Elementary Os and installed npm and npx. Now when I try to run  npx create-react-app myApp i am getting the following  error :

> npm ERR! cb.apply is not a function npm ERR! A complete log of this
> run can be found in: npm ERR!
> /home/user/.npm/_logs/2021-04-29T08_55_29_599Z-debug.log Install for [
> 'create-react-project@latest' ] failed with code 1

I found some answers on stack overflow but they didn't solve this. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
npx version:10.2.2

npm version: 7.10.0

node version :16.0.0
```

Comment: I am just trying to run $ npx create-react-project my project in the terminal

Comment: Watch this: https://github.com/nodejs/help/issues/2874#issuecomment-663661148

Comment: @NaorLevi I have tried that and didn't work. PS - I am running it on Linux

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I finally solved the error and i am going to keep this thread open if anyone else faces the same problem.

By default, npm installs packages in the local node_modules/ directory. Since npm i npm is shorthand for npm install npm, it will install the latest version of npm locally.

However, when run npm in a shell, the shell picks up the npm in your $PATH, which is probably the global installation.

To update the global installation of npm, run:

```
npm install --global npm
```